# Monotonocity of non-trivial solution of ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$y^{''}+q(x)y=0,q(x)<0$$ where $q(x)$  is a continuous function. Let $y$ be a non-trivial solution of ODE. How to prove that $y,y^{'}$ are strictly monotone functions? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about $q>0$ ? what about $y"+y=0$ ?

Comment: sorry its  negative...

Comment: This is false of course (play around with the solutions to $y''-y=0$, say), but similar statements are correct. However, your question is not really suitable for this site. Please ask at http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: i am asking for q is negative